# Javascript click button, inverse function

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to know what is the mistake on this js code, I need that the click expand the div and at the second click the div come back to the original dimension
This is the javascript:

```
<script> function myBurger() { 
    document.getElementById("burger").classList.toggle('expand'); 
    } 
    </script>
```

the relative html is this:

```
<div class="container" onclick="myBurger()">
  <input id="click" name="exit" type="checkbox" />
  <label for="click"><span class="burger"></span>       
</div>  

<div id="burger" > prova</div>
```

and this is the css:

```
 #burger{ 
 height: 10px; 
 width: 10px; 
 background-color: #fff; 
 top: 10%; 
 left: 10%; 
 position: absolute; 
 transition: height 2s ease, width 2s ease;
 } 

 #burger.expand{ 
 height: 200px; 
 width: 200px; 

 }
```

The complete code is there: www.figmentasergio.altervista.org

Comment: Your code works as expected, so what are you expecting? Describe desired behaviour. Just that you should close `label` tag

Comment: @j08691 Why would you use jQuery when you can use plain JavaScript?

Comment: @JuanMendes OP posted question using jQuery tag, that's why ;)

Comment: @j08691 I looked for a tag but didn't see one. `toggle` is a method of `classList` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList

Comment: @JuanMendes - Shows how often I use classList.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does work, you just don't see it because:

- Your div doesn't cause anything to reflow
- It doesn't have a background color or border

I've added a border to `#burger` so you can see it grow and shrink. I've also closed your `<label>` tag for tidiness.

```js
function myBurger() {
    document.getElementById("burger").classList.toggle('expand');
}
```

```css
#burger {
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    background-color: #fff;
    top: 10%;
    left: 10%;
    position: absolute;
    transition: height 2s ease, width 2s ease;
    border: 1px red solid;
}
#burger.expand {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" onclick="myBurger()">
    <input id="click" name="exit" type="checkbox" />
    <label for="click">
        <span class="burger"></span>
    </label>
</div>
<div id="burger">prova</div>
```

Comment: But it doesn't work on my web page. I put the border on my version and it don't work.
You can see it there: www.figmentasergio.altervista.org

Comment: @SergioVento You don't have a class called `.expand` in your CSS. You can see that the `expand` class is correctly being added to `#burger` as you click. Also, there's no border on your webpage